# Export your own user statistic

Tags: discussion, users

Is there any way to export the stats we have from Stack Overflow?

Like the Answers, Questions, Badges, etc.?

Comment: Possible Duplicate from Meta.StackExchange: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77331/export-my-stack-overflow-data

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could play around with the [monthly data dumps](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) or with the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/). You can query the Data Explorer based on your user ID.

The Data Explorer itself is Free Software, and has [extensive documentation](https://data.stackexchange.com/help). You will need a reasonable familiarity with SQL to use it to full effect.